# Angular 8 project (Previously 7) won't compile with Ionic 4 in production

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic4, angular8

Just upgraded an Angular7-Ionic4 project that worked fine to Angular8.
No problems so far with the hot-reload mode in the browser, but whenever I try to compile the project for android devices (in production mode) I get prompted with this error:

[The prompt error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3kv4.png)

I followed along with [this solution](https://medium.com/@JordanBenge/ionic-4-angular-ivy-the-future-is-now-old-man-dd9aca8bb905), but that didn't work either.

Comment: Same problem here 

Answer (score 0):

The builder-option in `angular.json` has to be changed from `ng-toolkit` to `angular-toolkit`.

Please see this [Github issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3763) for more info

Comment: I tried so many solutions for the past hour and this was one of them, sadly, it did not work.

Comment: and have you tried this too ?
When you use @ionic/angular-toolkit as a dependency, you also need to update angular.json by replacing all occurrences of @ionic/ng-toolkit and @ionic/schematics-angular by @ionic/angular-toolkit.